# Return type really long expression

Tags: c++, c++11, return-type

I have the following function:

```
inline auto iterateSomething(obj & o)
{
    auto iterators = baseIterator(o);
    auto tranformer = boost::bind(transofrmToSomething, _1, o);
    typedef boost::transform_iterator<decltype(tranformer), decltype(iterators.first)> iterator_t;
    iterator_t begin(iterators.first, tranformer);
    iterator_t end(iterators.second, tranformer);
    return std::make_pair(begin, end);
}
```

As you can see I don't know the return value and even if I put int there and later copy the type from the error message, its a really long type...
Is there a way to specify the return type as the type of the only return in the function? is there any workaround not involving a huge type in the return type?

Comment: typedefs are your friends, you could also define a metafunction to calculate the return type.

Comment: You can move the typedefs outside the function. Then you can use it to declare the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do what Raymond Chen suggested in a comment:

> Move the typedefs outside the function. Then you can use it to declare the return type.

If Raymond posts an answer it should be accepted in preference to mine--I'm posting this so that bitmask's answer is not the only one, since I think it is a cure worse than the disease.

Answer (score 0):

What about this, if you don't want to have your `typedef` moved out.

```
auto getIt = [] (obj& o, bool getEnd) {
  return boost::transform_iterator<
           decltype(boost::bind(transofrmToSomething, _1, o)),
           decltype(baseIterator(o).first)
         >(
           getEnd ? baseIterator(o).second : baseIterator(o).first,
           boost::bind(transofrmToSomething, _1, o)
         );
}

auto iterateSomething = [] (obj & o) {
  return std::make_pair(getIt(o,false), getIt(o,true));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the parameters for iterateSomething come after the []?

Comment: @VaughnCato: Nice catch, thanks! I changed it from a function and forgot to move the parameter list. Changed.

Comment: This is a C++ minefield: a ternary operator, the magic _1 (twice!), a bool parameter given as a number yet used as a selector, a variable called o right next to _1, decltype (twice!), auto (twice!), lambda expressions (twice!), and I'm still not sure if it's totally OK how decltype is being used on the "first" and not the "second."  It's barely clear what functionality is even being presented here, and now it's totally impenetrable.  Do what Raymond Chen said--future maintainers will thank you.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yes, I totally agree, your suggestion is definitely better and should be accepted ... oh, wait a minute.

Comment: OK, I posted Raymond's comment as an answer so that yours doesn't have to be accepted.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Of course you have ... but you still fail to explain how using C++ features (twice!) is bad. I'd like to see how you solve the issue with "your" `typedef` approach without a) having massive code duplication and more importantly b) using `decltype`.